# string comparison in php if condition is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to compare to a string but it is not working.

First I took it in my script and stored in a variable, and after that I stored the variable in the session.

This is my code...

```
<?php
    $currencyName1 = "<script>document.write(data);</script>";

    $_SESSION["currencyVal"] = $currencyName1;

    $price = strip_tags($this->session->userdata('currencyVal'));
    $price1 = substr($price,14,17);

    if (strcmp($price,"SAR")) {
        echo "SAR"; 
    } else {
        echo "USD"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: _...this is my code..._ What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: Also what is the intention behind the single slash before the `if`statement?

Comment: you probably need to check price1

Comment: we can't judge without the input value of $price variable can you add what you have inside $price variable

Answer (score 0):

Use cookie to get proper string 
Where as in $_SESSION you get value with script tags `<script>document.write(data);</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @lehmanad1, You need to perform comparison like strcmp($price1,"SAR"), and keep in mind that strcmp return result as follows.

```
strcmp returns:
0 - if the two strings are equal
<0 - if string1 is less than string2
>0 - if string1 is greater than string2
```

so that in your case the if condition return 0 if strcmp($price1,"SAR")gets true, and thus else condition will be executed.

you need to try following approach.

```
if (strcmp($price1,"SAR")==0) {
    echo "SAR"; 
} else {
    echo "USD"; 
}
```